# why my code show Warning message in ide "Access of shared member through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated"

Tags: vb.net

> I create class

```vb
'MyLib.aspx
Namespace MyLib
  Public Class Base

    Public Shared _XPage As Page
    Public Shared _Func  As FuncClass

    Public Shared Property XPage() As Page
      Get
          Return _XPage
      End Get
      Protected Set(Val as Page)
          _Page = Val
      End Set
    End Property 

    Public Sub New(ByVal Page As Page)
      XPage = Page
    End Sub
  End Class

  Public Class FuncClass : Inherits Base

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(_XPage)
    End Sub

    Public Function Test() As String
        Return "Test"
    End Function
  End Class
End Namespace
```

> I try it...

```vb
'ASPX_Page.aspx
Import MyLib

Partial Class ASPX_Page

  Private ReadOnly LibX As Base = New Base(Me)

  Protected Sub Button1_Clcik(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Handles Button1.Clcik

    'Access of shared member through an instance; 
    'qualifying expression will not be evaluated
     LibX._Func.Test()

  End Sub
End Class
```

> IDE show Warning message
>   "Access of shared member through an instance; qualifying expression will not > be evaluated", but still working fine
>
> why it show warning message , How can I fix it?

Comment: Shared in VB.net is equal to static in c#, You can access static resources by instance.

Comment: It seems quite odd to me that your `Base` class has a field of the derived type `FuncClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the warning because `_Func` is `Shared` and `Shared` members are supposed to be accessed via the type that they're a member of, not an instance of that type.  This:

```vb
LibX._Func.Test()
```

is trying to access `_Func` via an instance of the `Base` class rather than the class itself.  That should be like this:

```vb
Base._Func.Test()
```

If you want your `_Func` field to be instance-specific then don't declare it `Shared` and if you don't want it to be instance-specific then don't access it via a specific instance.

Note that this is a warning rather than an error.  If you do access a `Shared` member via an instance then the system will automatically ignore the instance and use the type, but it will tell you that it is doing so.  That's why you're being told that the qualifying expression, i.e. `LibX`, will not be evaluated.  It does that because someone might use a method that returns an instance rather than just a variable and that method would not be called, so anything else that that method also does would not happen.